# Does GeoNames allow to download street data as files, not through web service?

Tags: geolocation, geocoding, reverse-geocoding

I've found, that GeoNames allows to download data for reverse geocoding (http://download.geonames.org/export/dump/readme.txt), but looks like in those files there's no street/street number information, am I missing something or they offer street information only through web service (which has request limits)?

Is any creative commons based data available for download with street information, in case GeoNames does not provide such information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenStreetMap provides data for streets and housenumbers.
On Geonames i only have found point based data, with one coordinate for a geo name